# How can I transform the jpg/bmp picture to a ROS .pgm map

Tags: ros, pgm

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a map of school's square generated by a GPS measuring instrument. The size of the square is 71.27m * 59.98m actually and is 71.27mm * 59.98mm in the CAD diagram.

And now I want to use this map as the navigation map based on ROS. The resolution unit of pgm map in ROS is usually 0.05m/pixel. However, the resolution of the .jpg picture is 144dpi*144dpi.

How can I transform the jpg/bmp picture to a ROS .pgm map? I know this transformation must properly be scaled so that one pixel in my map matches the resolution setting in AMCL. I have tried to make the change by Photoshop but failed.

So can you tell me the details about the change?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/374375/how-can-i-transform-the-jpg/bmp-picture-to-a-ros-.pgm-map/) by [alex_zt](https://answers.ros.org/users/72237/alex_zt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-03-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I will present an idea assuming that the package you are using is "[map_server](http://wiki.ros.org/map_server)".

The image format is not pgm, and the resolution is different, both of which I think can be solved by setting the yaml file.

> image : Path to the image file containing the occupancy data; can be absolute, or relative to the location of the YAML file

> resolution : Resolution of the map, meters / pixel

Example

```
image: xxx.jpg
resolution: 0.00001763888 # 0.024m/inch / 144dpi
origin: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0].
occupied_thresh: 0.65
free_thresh: 0.196
negate: 0
```

---

Originally posted by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) with karma: 1908 on 2021-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alex_zt](https://answers.ros.org/users/72237/alex_zt/) on 2021-03-28**:
Thank you for presenting the idea. i have try this.

But map_server tell the wrong.

Have you try this method before?

**Comment by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) on 2021-03-29**:
@alex_zt I've done "image: xxx.png" before, and I've changed the resolution, though not as small as 0.00001763888.
If you have a problem that has never been posted on ROS ANSWERS, why don't you create a question? Depending on the nature of the problem, we may be able to help.

**Comment by [alex_zt](https://answers.ros.org/users/72237/alex_zt/) on 2021-03-29**:
Ok, sir. Thank you. I will create this question